# Determine which version of Excel was used to create a .xls or .xlsx

Tags: c#, excel

I'm about to write an application to start .xls, .xlsx and .xlsm with the version of Excel used to create these files.
The reason is that they contain a lot of VBA scripts that work differently in different versions of Excel (thanks to Microsoft!).
I'm searching for a way to determine the version used to create such a file.

I have tried latebinding Excel and reading the `CalculationVersion` property but this shows me only the last version used to edit the file. Same for the version number in app.xml inside an .xlsx. It also seems the marker in the binary of the file is changing after editing and saving the file, though I am not sure all these markers change.

Does anyone know a marker or property which gives the version which *created* the file?

Please answer also if it works only for .xls or only for .xlsx. This will bring me a bit closer to my target.

Edit: to get the calculation version:

```
  private string CalculationVersion()

    {   //Variablen

        string version = String.Empty;

        object Object_Excel_Application = null;

        object Object_WorkBooks = null;

        object Object_WorkBook = null;

        object[] Parameters;

        Type Type_of_Programm;



        //Typ der Excel.Application bestimmen

        Type_of_Programm = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");



        //Eine Excel instanz erstellen und in Object_Excel_Application speichern

        Object_Excel_Application = Activator.CreateInstance(Type_of_Programm);



        try //Versuche

        {

            //Excel unsichtbar machen

            Parameters = new Object[1];

            Parameters[0] = 0;

            Object_Excel_Application.GetType().InvokeMember("Visible", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, Object_Excel_Application, Parameters);



            //Interaktion mit dem User unterbinden

            Parameters = new Object[1];

            Parameters[0] = 0;

            Object_Excel_Application.GetType().InvokeMember("Interactive", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, Object_Excel_Application, Parameters);



            //Workbooks erstellen

            Object_WorkBooks = Object_Excel_Application.GetType().InvokeMember("Workbooks", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, Object_Excel_Application, null);



            //Die angegebene Datei öffnen

            Parameters = new Object[15];

            Parameters[0] = dateiPfad;

            for(int i = 1; i <= 13; i++)

            {

                Parameters[i] = Missing.Value;

            }

            Parameters[14] = true;

            Object_WorkBook = Object_WorkBooks.GetType().InvokeMember("Open", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, Object_WorkBooks, Parameters);



            //Letzte Calculations Version auslesen

            version = Object_WorkBook.GetType().InvokeMember("CalculationVersion", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, Object_WorkBook, null).ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(version);



            //Wieder schließen

            //Workbook zumachen

            Parameters = new Object[3];

            Parameters[0] = true;

            Parameters[1] = Missing.Value;

            Parameters[2] = Missing.Value;

            Object_WorkBook.GetType().InvokeMember("Close", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, Object_WorkBook, Parameters);



            //Excel schließen

            Object_Excel_Application.GetType().InvokeMember("Quit", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, Object_Excel_Application, null);



            //Version in gekürtzter Form zurückgeben

            return version_long_to_version_short(version); //Die Hauptversionsnummer zurückgeben

        }//-try

        catch (Exception e) //bei Fehler

        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Message, "Error"); //Fehler anzeigen

            return String.Empty; //Leeren String zurückgeben

        }//-catch

        finally //Schlussendlich

        {

            //Die objecte wieder freigeben

            Object_freigeben(Object_WorkBook);

            Object_freigeben(Object_WorkBooks);

            Object_freigeben(Object_Excel_Application);

        }//-finally

    }//-CalculationVersion
```

Now I am trying to fix the problem that Excel 97 files seem not to store this, so I have this C++ that is used to determine if the bof of the file tells me that it is an Excel 97 (outputs 8) or any other version (outputs 0). The plan is to execute this and if it gives me a `0` I will get the `CalculationVersion`, otherwise I know that its Excel 97. `-1`, `-2`,`-3` are errors. The next step if this works is to "translate" my C++ to C# if possible and integrate it into my program.

Sorry for German comments but my English is not so good.

Comment: Perhaps this may get you going? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178605

Comment: Can someone translate that into C# im not very well in C++. this `// = 0x08 -> Biff5/Biff7/Biff8` and `i.e. 8 for Biff8 (Microsoft Excel 97, Excel 2000, Excel 2002)`this parts keeps me thinking because if more than one version uses the same how can i deicde wich version it is?

Comment: And if you save the document with an other version will it not rewrite the hole file with the "new" marker?

Comment: If you have version-dependent VBA code the usual way is to conditionally execute the code depending on the current Application.Version ... Why can't you do this, its much simpler than your current approach?

Comment: @Charles the VBA code in each file is a different and so each file has to be opened in the "right" version. It is not the goal to execute different VBA scripts if the file is opened in a "false" version. By double Clicking on the file the code has to chose the "creator" version and open the file with this version.

Comment: You don't need to execute different scripts. Why can't you change the VBA code in each file so that it works correctly in every version using conditional execution/compilation - its very easy to do (99% of the code won't change so you just isolate the small portions of code that do need to be changed) and its much more future proof than any other method  ...

Comment: @charlesWilliams We speak about more than 1500 file with different VBA scripts. So changing all the scripts is not possible. A other point is that they are confidential and i dont have the premission to acces all the file.

Comment: @Frederik, I understand, but AFAIK for VBA code the Excel version that was first used to create the code is meaningless. CalculationVersion gives you the Excel version that was last used to calculate the workbook before it was last saved. As you probably know, forward VBA compatibility is very good, with only a few rare exceptions.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams The CalculationVersion is the property i use. But i a user has opened a file in the wrong Version, renamed a column and saved it. Then it will give me the wrong version. But the main Problem is that a Excel 97 document seems not to store these version. In all my test (virtual WinXP maschine with Excel 97 and Excel Xp installed) it gives me the number of the version that is used in latebinding to retriev this property. So it gives me on my virtual maschine Excel Xp and on my real maschine Excel 2010. I will edit my question so that someone may check it.

Comment: The Workbook.CalculationVersion and Application.CalculationVersion properties were added in Excel 2000: so a file that has never been calculated and saved in XL2000 or later will not contain it: why not check for the absence? But there is a more fundamental problem: CalculationVersion has nothing much to do with the Excel version that originally created the file.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams Checking for the absence is not an option, because it does not returns a null or empty. You will get the version wich is used to open it in my case 2010 (and XP on virtual). Because of that i use the way over the C++ script to get the info of its year. I know about the fundamental problem but it seems to be not able to get the version wich "created" the file. There is no property and the binary headers are changed on save. The onlyst way is to use this or to store an info in each file(wich is not the best way because of 1500+ files).

Comment: Using VBA I get a zero from workbook.calculationversion when opening an Excel97 file in later versions, but only if you make sure that the workbook is not calculated at Open.

Comment: @charleswilliams can you show me how to aviod the calculation up on opening the excel file? this would help me a lot. i would be able to work without the C++ program.

Comment: @Frederik, Calculation is an Application level setting that is first set from the first non-template, non-addin workbook opened and is not changed by subseqently opened workbooks. So start an instance of Excel, open a new workbook, then Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual then open other workbooks in the same instance of Excel. If you want to save them without calculating you need to set Application.CalculateBeforeSave=False

Comment: @FrederikTerstappen: Regarding your comment about the "marker" being overwritten when saved with another version... I have a document created with Excel 2007, yet despite saving and overwriting many times with Excel 97 it still prompts, "WARNING: This file was created with a later version..." everytime I save. So _something_ is not being overwritten.